# Error while using npm packages for S3 multipart upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, npm, multipart

I am trying to upload video files into the s3 bucket using **multipart** upload npm package. So I tried some npm packages that already exist. e.g) S3-client, S3-upload-resume, etc. But every time I import this npm packages into my React code I will get an error in **node_modules** or something like **undefined** errors. I have no idea to solve these errors and Is there any modification should I need to do after installing that npm packages into my React project? I have spent so much time to find the solution for those errors. And also I would like to get some best way to upload video files into the s3 bucket (Multipart upload).  If anyone knows please give your suggestions.

**Sample Code**

```
var params = {
localFile: "some/local/file",

s3Params: {
    Bucket: "s3 bucket name",
    Key: "some/remote/file"
  },
};
var uploader = client.uploadFile(params);
uploader.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error("unable to upload:", err.stack);
});
uploader.on('progress', function() {
  console.log("progress", uploader.progressMd5Amount,
            uploader.progressAmount, uploader.progressTotal);
});
uploader.on('end', function() {
  console.log("done uploading");
});
```

**Error**

```
graceful-fs.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (graceful-fs.js:66)
at Object../node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js (graceful-fs.js:258)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:5)
at Object../node_modules/s3-client/lib/index.js (index.js:1501)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module../src/App.js (App.css?da7c:45)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module../src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object.0 (serviceWorker.js:135)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
at main.chunk.js:1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to add the code snippet that you are using and the error messages you are getting.

Comment: @strongjz I modified my question with sample code and error message.